# Updating the database with the data added to a backup after a crash

Tags: mysql, sql, otrs

Our MySQL database application crashed. We had a backup and restored it about a week after the system crashed. Meanwhile we used a backup database application. How can I add the data from this week's gap to the database.

What would be the best way to do this?

EDIT.

The table structure is the same. There are a number of tables with foreign keys.

Essentially my question boils down to this:

Primary keys on the two servers look like this:

```
serv1: 123456---

serv2: 123---456
```

All these are foreign keys in the secondary table

I would like to merge the two, but have all the primary keys in the second table to be reflected in the foreign key relationship when I move the corresponding data from the other tables.

Comment: Way too broad :( You want us to tell you how to get data from an application you tell us nothing about and write it to a database you tell us nothing about?

Answer (score 0):

If you have few versions of the database which i guess you do now, the best way is to synchronize the data between the online database and the missing data.

You can try with: http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-data-compare/
Or: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/

With workbench you can compare the schemas:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-database-diff-report.html

But the best first make an backup on test environment then try the compares, it could be that the same ID exists on two locations and you would need to find the best solution for your database.

- So put both databases (the live one and the latest database you have on two test environments)
- Synchronize them and check the differences

Run the fix on test if everything goes fine then do that on production.

Comment: The database schema is no different, but the indexes over lapping between then two.

Comment: This needs some manual work im afraid, no db synchronizer will fix this for you im afraid. are you familiar with the schema? you can always write a custom script to do the job?

Comment: I'm opting out for manual labor. The good thing is that PK table has only 12 keys at the end which are out of order. It is hooked to fks in 30 tables though.

Comment: 12 keys and how many records in total in the subtable? If its numbered like that i think you will be able to do it easily with queries. tell me if you need any help.

Comment: There are about 30 subtables with anywhere from 10 to ~100000 records in each one. I am setting all the foreign keys to cascade on update first. Then remap the pks.

Comment: I actually have it all set on test env with copies of both databases on the server.